# CDF for a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $Y$ be a continuous random variable with probability density function$$
> f_Y(x)=\begin{cases}
> xe^{-\frac{x^2}2};&x>0\\
> 0;&x\le0\end{cases}.$$
>   Compute $\mathbb{E}(Y)$ and determine the distribution of $Z$, where $Z=Y^2$.

This is what I think is correct for $\mathbb{E}(Y)$:
$$\mathbb{E}(Y)=\int_0^\infty\int_y^\infty xe^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}} \,\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y=\infty$$
This is not asked in the question but I am guessing the variance of $Y$ will also be infinity? It cannot be finite right?

And for the distribution function of $Z$, I'm a little bit stuck but this is what I have been able to do:

$$F_{Z}(z)=\mathbb{P}(Z \le z)=\mathbb{P}(X \le \sqrt z).$$

Edit: I realized I named my random variable $X$ rather than $Y$. Sorry!

Comment: The first one is wrong.  Look up how to compute $E(X)$ given the density function for $X$.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty P(Y \gt y) dy$ according to my book as long as the random variable is nonnegative

Comment: Do you mean to have the pdf as $ye^{\frac{-y^{2}}{2}}$?

Comment: @Remy I changed it, does it make more sense now?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}(Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\,f_{Y}(x)\, dx =  \int_{0}^{\infty} x \cdot x \exp(-\tfrac{x^{2}}{2})\, dx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$E(Y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf_Y(x)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$$

For the second part, you are on the right track.

If the support of $Y$ is on $(0,\infty)$ then so is $Z=Y^2$.

We have

$$\begin{align*}
F_Z(z)
&=P(Z\leq z)\\\\
&=P(Y^2 \leq z)\\\\
&=P(Y \leq \sqrt{z})\\\\
&=F_Y(\sqrt{z})\\
&\vdots
\end{align*}$$

where $P(Y^2 \leq z)=P(Y \leq \sqrt{z})$ because $Y$ does not take on negative values.

You need to integrate the PDF of $Y$ to get its CDF

Comment: For the first part, is an equal sign missing? If so, I think its the same thing as what I did: my book says that if the RV is nonnegative then $E(Y)=\int_0^\infty P(Y \gt y)dy=\int_0^\infty f_{Y}(x)x dx$. And for the second part why isn't it $P(-\sqrt z \le Y \le \sqrt z)?$

Comment: Thanks, fixed. I edited my answer with an explanation of why it's not $P(-\sqrt{z} \lt Y \lt \sqrt{z})$

Comment: Thanks!! It makes sense